# How to pass TTL in Cassandra Java Driver QueryBuilder?

Tags: java, insert, cassandra, datastax, ttl

I am using the QueryBuilder in the Cassandra Java driver to insert some data.

There seems to be no easy option to set the TTL on the row I am inserting.
None of the examples on the DataStax site show an example with TTL.

I suspect it has something to do with using() but once again, zero examples and minimal documentation in the code...

Answer (score 23):

Finally figured it out, you have to pass in the static ttl() method on the QueryBuilder itself:

```
.using(ttl(30));
```

Comment: To remove any possible confusion, the TTL value is in seconds.